# Xamarin Hot Restart Not Working on Windows, Visual Studio 16.9.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to do physical testing for an iOS app using Xamarin Forms following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart, but I am running into a problem when trying to debug to an iPhone or iPad. There have been no issues doing physical testing on Android through usb or simulation testing through MacInCloud, but I run into this error when deploying to iOS through usb for testing:

"Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous built version of your project.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it."

My Apple Developer Account is successfully linked to Visual Studio and I have iTunes installed, so I don't know what the issue could be relating to. I have tried all the common fixes, such as cleaning and rebuilding the file, restarting visual studio, and trying multiple devices.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: You could try to check the seetings in Build> Configuration Manager> Select the configuration(s) you wish to adjust, (e.g. Debug | iPhoneSimulator, Release | iPhone).  Make sure your shared library project(s) are included with the platform-specific configurations.

Comment: I appreciate the response. My configuration settings are set to 'Build' and 'Deploy' for the physical device. Can you be more specific about "shared library project(s) are included with the platform-specific configurations."? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: The build and deploy for physical device should be enough, please report a bug in visual studio to get VS teams' support (in VS help->Send Feedback->Report a problem).

Comment: Thank you, but I already did that a week ago and haven't heard back :(

Comment: @loganwenzel you can follow up with your feedback here in bellow link, I see the team is asking for some information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Hot-Restart-not-working-on-Windo/1376340